# Why do high efficiency water heaters require outside air vents and drains?

Tags: water-heater

All high efficiency water heaters seem to require PVC air *intake* and vent; the existing water heater I have doesn't have a drain connection or intake vent; only a traditional chimney. What are these used for in high efficiency designs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low efficiency water heaters are low efficiency because their exhaust gases are very hot. Since the gases are hot, they will rise up a chimney flue with ease, but this also means you lose all that energy and warm air up your flue. Older heaters tend to be in older homes where there are enough drafts and air leakage to not worry too much about ventilation. One other thing: the hot air also carries also the moisture produced by combustion up and out the chimney.

High efficiency heaters try to reduce the temperature of the exhaust gases as much as possible in order to recover as much energy as possible. But as the exhaust gas is almost room temperature, it won't rise and thus has to be forcibly expelled. The moisture that is produced by combustion will also condense in the cooler air and will have to be drained out of a separate drain line.

High efficiency furnaces are also designed to be used in high efficiency houses that are well sealed, so you need to bring in fresh air lest you run the heater too lean and produce carbon monoxide. Another reason to bring in fresh outside (cold) air is that it is a waste to use the inside (warm) air for combustion and blow it outside the house.

Heat exchangers are used on the intake and outtake gases which further increase efficiency. This necessitates both intake and exhaust vents.

<sub>Thanks to commentator keshlam for additional material that was brought into the answer</sub>

Comment: Also, drawing combustion air from outside avoids pulling already-heated air out of your house. The drain is needed because extracting the additional heat causes condensation, as the exhaust gasses are no longer warm enough to hold all the water produced by combustion.

Comment: Btw, chimneys can be reused if you prefer ... but since the chemistry of the exhaust gasses is different, they generally have to be relined for the new system. That's enough hassle/cost that "direct venting" of both intake and exhaust is usually simpler. (And in my case, it let me get rid of an ugly chimney when I re-roofed, which also removes one source of leaks and will eventually let me reclaim a few square feet.)